# Setup Spring Filter using annotation

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am really new to spring and wanted to make a simple web application that uses JWT based authentication.
I have an endpoint on my server (`/token`) that returns JWT tokens to my client.

These clients then make requests to my server using that token. I was wondering how I could implement something like this:

```
@Secured("Admin")
@RequestMapping("/users", method=RequestMethod.DELETE)
public @ResponseBody String deleteUsers(){
   ...
}
```

From what I could gather, I would need a filter that would validate my JWT  token that is sent along with every request the client makes. Is there any way in which only requests that have a `@Secured` annotation are passed through that filter?

Answer (score 0):

Spring Security maintains a filter chain internally where each of the filters has a particular responsibility and filters are added or removed from the configuration depending on which services are required. The ordering of the filters is important as there are dependencies between them. If you have been using namespace configuration, then the filters are automatically configured for you and you don't have to define any Spring beans explicitly but here may be times when you want full control over the security filter chain, either because you are using features which aren't supported in the namespace, or you are using your own customized versions of classes.
[link](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/security-filter-chain.html)